# Randomly generated tunnel walls that don't jump around from one to the next

Tags: ios, algorithm, random

I'm generating a sort of tunnel that you can fly through, in a 2D screen. I want the walls to smoothly move from left to right randomly. Right now I just end up with "spikes".

I want it to look like this

[image]

instead of this

[image]

I'm using code for the walls that looks like this, forty times each left and right.

```
if (Left1.center.y > 568) {
    RandomPosition = arc4random() %55;
    Left1.center = CGPointMake(RandomPosition, 0);
    RandomPosition = RandomPosition + 265;
    Right1.center = CGPointMake(RandomPosition, 0);
}
```

and then this

```
RandomPosition = arc4random() %55;
Left1.center = CGPointMake(RandomPosition, 0);
RandomPosition = RandomPosition + 265;
Right1.center = CGPointMake(RandomPosition, 0);
```

but it doesnt really move the walls the way I want.

Comment: Well, the thing is that the one you like is not independently random. Each successive "wall" of the tunnel varies by a small (perhaps random) amount _from the wall preceding it_, plus the direction of that variation (further to left or further to right) changes only very rarely, not at random. You'll have to program that into your algorithm.

Comment: You need to add some sort of tolerance check to the random number.  If its outside the tolerance from the last number, generate another number. The CPU in iOS device can generate at least a millions per second.  :-)

Comment: These algorithms can be a lot of fun, because you can introduce as much or as little complexity as you want. For example, you could choose to be increasing or decreasing by *randomAmount* for *randomNumberOfSteps* with *randomVariation* each time.

Comment: Also this is a sine wave. so program around that.

Comment: I don't think it's meant to be _exactly_ a sine wave, @JohnRiselvato, just _sinuous_, but the values of `sin()` could definitely be a starting point.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is called "correlated" random number generation.

One of the most popular ways of generating such numbers is called [Perlin noise](http://devmag.org.za/2009/04/25/perlin-noise/), which may be too complicated for your needs.

The simplest thing to do in your case would be to keep track of the last wall position, and generate a random *offset* from that, instead of the number generator being used for the bare value of the wall. This is known as a ["random" or "drunken" walk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk).

To keep the tunnel's width the same, randomly pick only the left wall's end point, then put the right wall's end the correct distance away.

```
CGFloat leftWallX = /* starting value */;
for( int i = 0; i < NUM_WALLS; i++ ){
    // Generate a number from -MAX_OFFSET to MAX_OFFSET
    CGFloat offset = (CGFloat)arc4random_uniform(2*MAX_OFFSET) - MAX_OFFSET;
    leftWallX += offset;
    rightWallX = leftWallX + tunnelWidth;
    //...
}
```

Comment: Google for "Drunkard's Walk"

Comment: +1 for the tip about keeping the tunnel width constant.

Comment: Do you have a general example of what could be used for a correlated random number generator?

Comment: You can still use `arc4random_uniform()` or whatever you're using now, @user3570841; you really just need to change the way you use it.

Comment: Added a snippet that should give you the idea @user3570841.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to inc. this in to it. I have 41 walls altogether that i'm using and the walls are named Left1 and Right1. i had something like this

    CGFloat Left1 = 14;

    for( int i = 0; i < 41; i++ ){

    CGFloat offset = (CGFloat)arc4random_uniform(2*100) - 100;

    Left1 += offset;

    Right1 = Left1 + 100;
but it was telling me as a yellow text that Local declaration of "Left1" hides instance variable and then in a red text it says "Assigning to 'UIImageView *__strong' from incompatible type 'float'. i'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Well, you have a wall named `Left1`, and then you’re declaring a new `CGFloat` named `Left1` just before your loop. And since your original `Left1` is a `UIImageView` and your new one is a `CGFloat`, they are of incompatible type.

Comment: Also, do you have 82 views called `Left1`, `Right1`, `Left2`, `Right2`, etc? If so, you may want to consider keeping them in an array in accordance with [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).