# What algorithm can I use to turn a drunkards walk into a correlated RNG?

Tags: ios, random, viewcontroller

I'm a novice programmer (the only reason I say this is because I'm not super familiar with all the terms yet) and I'm trying to make walls generate in respect to the wall before it. I've posted a question about it on here before

[Randomly generated tunnel walls that don't jump around from one to the next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23301197/randomly-generated-tunnel-walls-that-dont-jump-around-from-one-to-the-next)

and sort of got the answer. What I was mainly looking for was the for loop that was used (I think). Th problem is I didn't know how to implement it properly without getting errors.

My problem ended up being "I couldn't figure out how to inc. this in to it. I have 41 walls altogether that i'm using and the walls are named Left1 and Right1. i had something like this

```
CGFloat Left1 = 14; for( int i = 0; i < 41; i++ ){ 
CGFloat offset = (CGFloat)arc4random_uniform(2*100) - 100; 
Left1 += offset; 
Right1 = Left1 + 100;
```

but it was telling me as a yellow text that Local declaration of  "Left1" hides instance variable and then in a red text it says "Assigning to 'UIImageView *__strong' from incompatible type 'float'. i'm not sure how to fix this"

and I wasn't sure how to fix it. I realize (I think) that arc4random and arc4random_uniform are pretty much the same thing, as far as i know, with slight differences, but not the difference i'm looking for.

As I said before, i'm pretty novice so any example would really be helpful, especially with the variables i'm trying to use. Thank you.

Comment: The error means that: `Left1` is a variable within your function but at the same time you have a class level variable/property called `Left1`. This means that the local one will be used instead of the class level one. Secondly, it says that some variable is a `UIImageView` but you are assigning a `float` to it.

Comment: How could I rewrite this to make it appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

You want a "hashing" function, and preferably a "cryptographic" one because they tend to be significantly higher quality - at the expense of requiring additional CPU resources. But on modern hardware the extra CPU power usually isn't a problem.

The basic idea is you can give any data to the function, and it will spit out a completely random result, but always the same result if you provide the same input.

Have a read up on them here:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

There are hundreds of different algorithms in common use, which is best will depend on what you need.

Personally I recommend sha256. A quick search of "sha256 ios" here on stack overflow will show you how to make one, with the CommonCrypto library. The gist is you should create an `NSString` or `NSData` object that contains every offset, then run the entire thing through sha256. The result will be a perfectly random 256 bit number.

If 256 bits is too much, just cut it up. For example you could grab just the first 16 bits of the number, and you will have a perfectly random 16 bit number.

Comment: Umm.. was this answer meant for another question?