# How can I create an offset on a UIImageView

Tags: ios, methods, uiimageview, correlated

I recently posted a question on here

[Randomly generated tunnel walls that don't jump around from one to the next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23301197/randomly-generated-tunnel-walls-that-dont-jump-around-from-one-to-the-next?rq=1)

That pretty much said I was getting a "drunken walk" tunnel instead of a correlated one due to a lack of an algorithm.

The answer works to an extent for what I'm attempting to create but I couldn't figure out how to implement the algorithm properly for my game.

I believe step one is to create the offsets for the pairs of walls. I want the images that appear (named: "Left1" and "Right1" , "Left2 and "Right2".... "Left41" and Right41") on each side of the screen to be "re-spawning" slightly offset to the left or right in succession of each other in order to create the illusion of a tunnel in appearance. I attempted to use the code provided to me in an answer to create an offset for a set of my walls but I get few errors when attempting to build. It was telling me first that a local declaration of 'Left1' hides instance variable, which I believe is because it's been declared already as a variable within my function? That came up twice.. Along with that I have an error that says Assigning to 'UIImageView *__strong' from incompatible type 'float'. How can I fix these? Or is it something I'm doing wrong elsewhere?

I'm kind of lost on this part since I don't know how to really rearrange it, due to the semantic issues.

I can answer any questions about the program to make it easier to assess the situation.

```
-(void) TunnelMovement{

    CGFloat Left1 = 14;
    for( int i = 0; i < 41; i++ ){
        CGFloat offset = (CGFloat)arc4random_uniform(2*100) - 100;
        Left1 += offset;
        Right1 = Left1 + 14;
        //...
    }
}
```

This is what I have exactly in my code after trying to fill in the blanks from the answer given. Not sure if I put in all the necessities or what. Thank you.

Comment: As you have already been told (in your deleted post), "Assigning to 'UIImageView *__strong' from incompatible type 'float'." is due to assigning a variable of type float to a variable of type UIImageView. As you have been unable to solve this small one line error message after a few days it can only mean you have no programming experience at all. May I kindly suggest you take time out and read a few basic tutorials on the fundamentals on programming before continuing otherwise you will just continue to not understand and/or apply any answers given to you unless spoonfed

Comment: But feel free to post the line of code that displays the error and I will be happy to correct it (its proably the last line above right - so you need to post the code before that too, the one that includes the declaration or Right1)

Comment: The error is coming from the Right1 = Left1 + 14;

the other 2 yellow warnings are from that line and the line above it

Comment: You need to show the code before that, you must be declaring Right1 as a UIImageView earlier in the code which isn't shown here.

Comment: Yes, I have it declared as an IBOutlet UIImageView

Comment: Give me a few minutes to write something as an ansser

Answer (score 0):

[I can give you quick correction on that error message, but you are trying to run and you can't even walk yet, you can barely crawl. 
Stack Overflow is a programming forum but it is not the place to learn or teach programming, people won't have the patience to teach basics.]

You can't assign the value of one thing to another if they are totally different things. In the line:

```
Right1 = Left1 + 14;
```

Right1 is a UIImageView and Left1 is a CGFloat, they are completely different things. Left1 is just a simple number, Right1 is a complex object.

You're trying to position UIImageView so you need to assign the value of Left1 + 14 to a part of the UIImageView that will position it and which is also a CGFloat.

So you need to assign it to something like the bounds or the frame or the center's x value, such as

```
Right1.center.x = Left1 + 14;
```

The warning is because you have two different things with the same name, you have  UIImageView called Left1 but then you have a CGFloat also called Left1, you shouldn't give the same name to two different things - the CGFloat Left1 hides the UIImageView called Left1. You should have called it Left1X or LeftWallX or similar as it is in the answer to your other question.

That's just the error and warning, you're probably not ready to move on to the semantics of how to draw the maze if you were strugging with these two. In particular you will as a minimum need to know what the bounds, frame, center, x, y, CGPoint, CGRect, CGSize all are in order to fully understand what value to change and what effect changing those values will have on the position of the UIImageViews.

---- EDIT --- object programming 101

When you have an object like UIImageView it is like a having a house, the house can have a name and have lots of rooms in it, each with a name, within each room there are lots of things. You are trying to do the equivalent of replace the old television in one room with a new television.

So Right1 is like a house

Right1.center is like a room in a house

Right1.center.x is like the television in the room called center which is in the house called Right1.

```
Right1 = Left1 + 14;
```

is like trying to swap a new television for a house, instead of trying to swap it for a televsion within a room within a house.

Is that analogy too dumb?

Comment: Alright so I changed the Left1's in that specific method to Left1X and it seemed to fix it. The only red error i'm getting now is "Use of undeclared Identifier 'Right1X'. since i have this now 


-(void) TunnelMovement{
    
    CGFloat Left1X = 14;
    for( int i = 0; i < 41; i++ ){
        CGFloat offset = (CGFloat)arc4random_uniform(2*100) - 100;
        Left1X += offset;
        Right1X.center.x = Left1X + 14;
        //...
    }
}

but you explained it very well. There aren't a ton of places I know to learn xcode besides here and random youtube videos.

Comment: There's lots of great books. But its not Objective C you need to learn, its programming in general. There's books on Amazon that teach iOS development for people with no previous programming experience. They teach programming as well as iPhone app writing, which is what you need. Right1.center.x = ... not Right1X.center.x = ...

Comment: I figured it would have to be something else since when I try to do it  with Right1.center.x, it tells me that the expression is not assignable.

Comment: I've added an object programming 101 lesson part at the end of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. Obviously we have attempted to jumped into programming to quickly! Gonna continue reading & educating ourselves for the next few months.  

also, I just wanna solve this one method before ending the chat. Could you help me out on why it says "The expression is not assignable" for the line of 

Right1.center.x = Left1X + 14;  with the error being under the equal sign i believe.